# Format double value in custom scientific notation

Tags: c#, .net, formatting

I am formatting my values as follows:

```
string text = value.ToString("0.000E0##");
```

This seems to work for some numbers, i.e.:

```
0.1          -> 1.000E-1
0.12         -> 1.200E-1
0.123        -> 1.230E-1
0.1234       -> 1.234E-1
1.2E-34      -> 1.200E-34
1.23E-45     -> 1.230E-45
```

...but fails with others, i.e.:

```
0.12345      -> 1.234E-15 //INCORRECT
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find in the [custom numeric format string specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) what the `##` after the `E0` in the format string should mean, what do you want exactly?

I think that you should only use `0.000E0`, which works as expected.

Comment: I want the exponent to contain at least one digit, and a maximum of 3 digits.

Comment: Looks like the extra `#` symbols after the `E` in the original format string just match the digits of the mantissa, which gets really confusing

Comment: @BoroDrummer, as far as I remember, double precision will give you exponent that is at most around 300 in absolute value, so you are fine here.

Comment: @Paolo Tedesco, your format string of "0.000E0" seems to work perfectly. I think I was over thinking this one. Thanks all for the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

**You could specify a custom format like so.**

```
var num = 3147.3;
num.ToString("\\0.#####E0"); // "0.31473E4"
```

Hope this helps..